# "Having been" vs. "having had" vs. "having being"

Tags: meaning

I need help in distinguishing the difference in meanings among these three usage and which seems to be the most grammatically accurate? The "Having +..." seem to all have very similar context, so I'm confused.

1. Having being burdened by the idol-actress title
2. Having had burdened by the idol-actress title
3. Having been burdened by the idol-actress title

Thanks so much!

Answer (score 2):

The difference is that the third is grammatical, and the other two are not.

"Have" (has, had, having),  as an auxiliary, is always followed by a past participle, so "having being" is ungrammatical.*

What's wrong with the second example is that it is trying to use "have + pp" twice in the same verb phrase. Simple-past 'had' can be used as an auxiliary "had burdened" but the past-participle 'had' cannot.

But "having been burdened" is fine: it's "having + pp", the pp in question being that of 'be', in the passive construction "be burdened".